# Game Server Language Selection

Tags: c#, java, php

I am planning to make a online-multiplayer game with my friends.
The game is a browser card game (so, players act in turns) and players could host rooms in a lobby.
Flex + actionscript will be used to write for the client side.
We are discussing what should be used for the server side.

I suggested C#/Java and my friend suggested PHP.

I kw there are couple of questions asking for what language to use but I think it should depend on specific conditions.

Is there any suggestion for us? Thanks.

Additional infomation: most logic will be implemented by the server since we want to reduce the chance of cheating.

Comment: *"reduce the chance of cheating"* reducing isn't good enough. You should *zero* it.

Answer (score 3):

You should base your decision on what language you are the most familiar with, as any server language would work just as well for this.

Comment: We want to know more about the ease of development, extension...etc.

Comment: But ease of development is about proportional with how much you know the language beforehand.
I'm a .NET-geek trying to learn RoR. So for me PHP would be out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing anything else about your programming knowledge/experience, or your server setup, I'm just going to suggest PHP. It's easy to learn, and it exists on virtually every shared hosting plan you can find. It is already ready for web development out of the box with no framework and with a little effort you can actually code it quite nicely.

However, if you are have privileged access to the server, already know C# or Java or whatever and can get up and running equally fast no matter what you choose, then it's up to your preference.

Just take the path of least resistance and your project will turn out better, sooner.